# Do we have a built-in merge functionality implemented to deduct possible duplicate questions?

Tags: feature-request

I shouldn't expand this question too much, the title say enough. i noticed that questions which have been marked as a duplicate are still stand-alone questions, but have not been merged to the *original* question, if questions are identical for 70%+ should we melt it together with just **one** path?

Answer (score 3):

No - there is no intention to do this. Having duplicates remain offers more landing points for individuals searching.

We do have functionality for certain types of merge as needed, but that is for answers, not questions.